# Convert Secure Binding from config file to Coding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

Want to call HTTPS WCF services.  When we're calling like this:

```
SmartPayments2SoapClient client = new SmartPayments2SoapClient();
```

it is working correctly.

But in my scenario i don't want to use default binding. It must be created programmatically but in this, my services is secure mean it's running on HTTPS.

Please suggest me code where i can create binding programmatically.

Here is the App.config with custom binding:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="SmartPayments2Soap12">
        <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </textMessageEncoding>
        <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

I want this to be converted in C# program. I have tried this:

```
SecurityBindingElement securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateSslNegotiationBindingElement(false);
HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
httpsTransport.AllowCookies = false;
httpsTransport.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
httpsTransport.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
httpsTransport.MaxBufferSize = 65536;
httpsTransport.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
httpsTransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;
httpsTransport.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
httpsTransport.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
httpsTransport.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
httpsTransport.ManualAddressing = false;
httpsTransport.AllowCookies = false;
httpsTransport.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
//httpsTransport.DecompressionEnabled = true;
httpsTransport.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
httpsTransport.KeepAliveEnabled = true;
httpsTransport.ProxyAuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
httpsTransport.Realm = "";
httpsTransport.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
httpsTransport.UnsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication = false;
httpsTransport.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;

CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, httpsTransport);

EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("https://example.com/Payments/Transact2.asmx");

SmartPayments2SoapClient client = new SmartPayments2SoapClient(binding, remoteAddress);
```

Comment: So asmx or wcf service?

Comment: @abatishchev all the config settings looks like WCF to me.

Comment: @RichardSchneider: Yes, except the last line: `Transact2.asmx`.

Comment: @abatishchev You have better eyes than me! +1

Comment: @RichardSchneider: Everything else is proper WCF code, indeed. Thus I'm wondering what is going on here :)

Comment: @Kushal: Why do you point .asmx file while WCF service has .svc extension?

Comment: Its .asmx service... just i want to call asmx service at runtime created binding and endpoing for HTTPS service...

Comment: It would be very helpful if u have any idea to create Runtime binding code for secure ASMX service

Comment: Hey finally found the ans.. i created TextMessageEncodingBindingElement object and add in EndpointAddress.. and its worked for me